# How does current flow in a short circuit?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, short-circuits

In a short circuit, the potential difference across the terminals of a battery (consider a single cell with internal resistance)is 0 according to the equation 
$$V=E-Ir,$$
where $r$ is internal resistance of the cell,$E$ is the emf of the cell and $V$ is a potential difference across the battery.

If the potential difference across any two points in a circuit is 0, the electric current $I$ doesn't flow right? Then how does current flow in a short circuit (assume 0 resistance for short-circuited wire)?

Comment: Please don't write in all capitals, as that's the equivalent of yelling. Further, you should come up with more descriptive title so that other users can know what you're asking.

Comment: Forget the word, "short." It may be useful to talk about a "short circuit" when you are trying to describe a _fault condition_ in some electrical system, but that phrase is not useful when you're analyzing a circuit. It's _just_ a circuit. The circuit that you have described (a practial battery whose terminals are directly connected) can be modeled as an ideal voltage source in parallel with the battery's internal resistance. Now, try asking why current flows...

Comment: ...But that's an electrical engineering question.  If you want to ask a _physics_ question, try asking this:  How is it possible for current to flow in a length of superconducting wire when the voltage difference between the two ends of the wire is zero?

Answer (score 2):

If there can be no current between two points where the potential difference is zero, then there can be no current flowing in ideal  wires (wires with zero resistance) that connect together voltage sources and circuit elements that do have impedance. Obviously, that is not the case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What happens to the Ohm's law in this particular case ? Why does it give an undefined value ? Are there assumptions that are violated ?

Comment: @Bemipefe Ohm's law can be written $V=IR$. If $R$ is zero, then $V$ can be zero without $I$ having to be zero. This simply means there is no electrical resistance impeding constant current and therefore no electric force is required to do work to move the charge. The mechanical analogy is an object moving at constant velocity on a perfectly frictionless surface. No mechanical force is needed.

Comment: In other words this means that $I$ can be anything if $V$ and $R$ are zero. Anyway you said that the current also is zero if $V$ is zero but $V \over R$ is undefined for $R = 0$. What am I missing ?

Comment: @Bemipefe I never said the "current is also zero if $V$ is zero". What you are missing is understanding the definition of potential difference, or voltage, which is: The potential difference, $V$, between two points is the work required per unit charge to move the charge between the two points. If there is no electrical resistance between two points (i.e., force resisting motion of the charge) then no work is required to move the charge between the points, ergo, $V=0$. Think in terms of Newton's first law: An object in motion tends to stay in motion unless acted upon by an external force.

Comment: This law applies equally to charge as it does to mass.

Comment: I was referring to this sentence _"...there can be no current flowing in ideal wires (wires with zero resistance) that connect together voltage sources and circuit elements that do have impedance..."_ . I read this as if $R = 0$ then $I = 0$. My question is how do you infer that $I = 0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Think about a conventional (idealized) circuit with an ideal voltage source driving current through a resistor. I am sure you agree that current
$$ I = \frac{U}{R}$$
will flow.

Now take any two points between resistor and voltage source. The voltage drop between them is zero (in practice), but still a current flows!

This means, you will always find pairs of points in a typical circuit with current flow made of resistors and very low resistance wires, between which the resistance (e.g. of the cables) is negligibly small, and therefore the voltage drop in the presence of current flow is essentially zero.

Comment: probably, the best explanation, thnx :)